# Translate $2xy=x^2-y^2$ to polar coordinates

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

> As per the title i need to translate $2xy=x^2-y^2$ into a polar coordinates function

Why it confuses me:

$$
x = r\cos\phi\\
y = r\sin\phi
$$

Then:

$$
2r^2\cos{\phi}\sin{\phi} = r^2\cos{\phi}-r^2\sin{\phi} = r^2(\cos^2{\phi} - \sin^2{\phi}) \\
r^2\sin{2\phi}=r^2\cos{2\phi} \\
sin{2\phi} = \cos{2\phi}
$$

Which gives:

$$
\phi = \frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{\pi n}{2}, \;\;\;\;
n \in \mathbb Z
$$

But it's just a set of $\phi$ values. How do i plot such a function? In polar coordinates $r$ is a function of some $\phi$, isn't that?

Comment: How did you get to your second line of working out?

Comment: Draw the graph of $2xy=x^2-y^2$ in cartesian coordinates and the graph of $\phi = \frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{\pi n}{2}$ in polar coordinates. Lo and behold, they are the same.

Comment: When eliminating $r^2$ on should add $\/ r=0$ but that is irrelevant: 4 spokes with $n \in \{0, 1, 2, 3\}$ through O.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $$
\phi= \frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{\pi n}{2}, \;\;\;\;
n \in \mathbb Z
$$

and not $x$.

So $$x= r\cos (\frac{\pi}{8} + \frac{\pi n}{2})=$$
$$ = r(\cos \frac{\pi}{8} \cos \frac{\pi n}{2}-\sin \frac{\pi}{8} \sin \frac{\pi n}{2})$$
Now try to put $n=0,1,2,3,4...$. We see that:

if we put $n=0,4,8...$ we get the same value.
  if we put $n=1,5,9...$ we get the same value.
...

So write $n= 4k+r$ where $r\in\{0,1,2,3\}$ and you will get 4 different families of solution.

Comment: That was a mistake in the OP, i meant $\phi$. Thanks for spotting

Comment: How did you get that $n = 4k+r $ ?

Comment: Because of part ${\pi n \over 2}$ and $2\pi $ is basic period of $\cos $

Comment: That is still confusing to me, i don't really get it.

Answer (score 3):

After conversion to polar coordinates, $r$ disappears from the equations (but for $r=0$, which corresponds to the origin). This means that for a given $\phi$, $r$ is arbitrary and this describes an infinite straight line through the origin and with direction $\phi$.

---

By the way, you can obtain the same result by plugging the equation of a straight line through the origin, $y=mx$, which gives

$$2mx^2=x^2-m^2x^2$$ or

$$2m=1-m^2$$ or

$$m=\pm\sqrt2-1.$$

Answer (score 2):

What to expect:

$x^2-2xy-y^2= 0;$

$(x-y)^2-2y^2 =0;$

$(x-y-√2y)(x-y+√2y)= 0;$

1)$x = y(1+√2)$,or $y= (1+√2)^{-1}x$;

2) $y=(1-√2)^{-1}x;$

1)and 2) are 2 lines passing through the origin.

Slopes: $m_1= -1+√2$ ; $m_2=-1-√2$.

Perhaps not so surprising any more your result in polar coordinates.

Comment: You could also just examine the discriminant of this degenerate conic to determine that it’s a pair of straight lines through the origin.

Comment: amd.Thanks for your comment.Greetings.

Answer (score 1):

The graph of $\phi =c$ where $c$ is a constant, is just a ray through the origin  which makes an angle of $\phi$ with the positive direction of $x$-axis.

Answer (score 1):

Accoring to the equation $$\sin 2\phi=\cos 2\phi,$$ we can obtain $$\phi=\frac{4n+1}{8}\pi,n \in \mathbb {Z}.$$ But in fact,

- $\phi=2k\pi+\dfrac{1}{8}\pi$,when $n=4k$;
- $\phi=2k\pi+\dfrac{5}{8}\pi$,when $n=4k+1$;
- $\phi=2k\pi+\dfrac{9}{8}\pi$,when $n=4k+2$;
- $\phi=2k\pi+\dfrac{13}{8}\pi$,when $n=4k+3$.

These are four rays，which are reverse pairwisely. In another word, they're two lines as follows

[image]

## Another method

You can directly solve the equation $$y^2+2xy-x^2=0.$$ Therefore, $$y=\frac{-2x \pm \sqrt{(2x)^2-4 \cdot 1 \cdot (-x^2)}}{2}=(-1 \pm \sqrt 2)x.$$ This also represents the two lines.